# Physically moving Windows8 UEFI drive to a non UEFI equipped laptop

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi

Moving a 500GB laptop drive from an unavailable deck used UEFI.

Moving it to the non UEFI NO CSM booting deck of same manufacture.

Drive works fine, I have to reboot the drive and UEFI infected OS in its last user state for settings, browser settings and nuances.

There has to be a way to do this, already formatted a USB drive with DiskPart and formatted it, set it active then copied the Windows8 ..\efi*  to the root of the USB and the author of that blogpost is likely hiding somewhere from those before me seeking satisfaction while he enjoys his private laugh.

The root of the USB drive (omitting pasting the 30+ language directories)

- boot.stl
- bootmgfw.efi
- bootmgr
- bootmgr.efi
- BOOTNXT
- bootx64.efi
- memtest.efi

> So far, there's no authoritative source on how UEFI is supposed to run
>   and neither I or anyone else that would benefit from the solution are
>   served by responders disagreeing with my assertion with a mindless
>   link to an IEEE pdf.

Comment: Your question has too much unnecessary personal information, try to limited to what the facts are and point out what your problem is so people don't have to read a novel to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your post isn't all that clear. For instance, what do you mean by "deck?" To what blog post are you referring? It sounds like you want to move an internal disk from one computer to another, so how a USB drive fits into this plan is unclear. You don't say so explicitly, but I get the impression that the disk is a boot disk. (If it's not, this is much simpler, because every version of Windows since Vista SP2 can read GPT disks just fine, even when booted in BIOS mode. It's only when *booting* from a GPT disk that EFI is required.)

For the basic question of converting Windows to boot in EFI mode to booting in BIOS mode, that's tricky. It requires:

- Converting the GPT-partitioned disk to using MBR partitions. You can do this by performing a backup-repartition-restore operation or by using certain disk utilities (such as [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) and certain commercial Windows tools) to convert in place. The standard Windows tools, when asked to do such a conversion, will *erase* current partitions, so don't use them except as part of a backup-repartition-restore operation.
- Installing a BIOS-mode boot loader on the disk. I don't know of any explicit instructions for doing this for an EFI-to-BIOS boot-mode conversion, although I do have a [link to a site that describes the opposite conversion.](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) That might or might not be helpful to you.

Be aware that Microsoft ties Windows installations to specific computers, and Windows is also quite picky about drivers. Thus, even if you successfully complete both of the two tasks that I've outlined, you might have quite a challenge ahead of you to get the OS to boot and work. You might need a new license key.

Overall, it's almost certainly easier to re-install Windows fresh on the new computer.